# Where is the new Rails welcome screen located?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

I created new rails application with commands:

```
rails new myapp --webpack=react
webpacker:install
webpacker:install:react
```

When I add `javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react'` nothing happens and the homepage does not include the promised hello.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>
      </head>

      <body>
        <%= yield %>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I figure this is not the layout that Rails uses since the title says "Ruby on Rails" instead of my application name. Also the react part isn't rendering. **What am I missing?**

Comment: can you show me your component?

Comment: What you are showing is the application.html.erb file. This is basically the header of all the views on your website. Create a controller, create views for this controller actions (only one is needed) and then you will be able to see an actual webpage with above header

Comment: @uzaif it's the default entry component created by rails 5.1.2. Maxence - I understand, but editing the default view (homepage) should also be a possibility..

Comment: why dont you create root `routes` and add your component in it,

Comment: You should be able to see your "Hello react from webpack" when you create a new controller with an action in it, say `rails g controller home index`, and when you define this action action as your root in your route file